# Liquid template in Padrino can't get instance variable

Tags: ruby, sinatra, liquid, padrino

I try to convert a ramaze app to padrino(0.12.1)
Current problem that I have is instance variable in padrino/sinatra controller can't be read by liquid template.

**controllers/main.rb**

```
Myproject::App.controllers :main do
  get :index, :map => '/' do
    @name = 'foo'
    render 'main/index'
  end
```

**views/layouts/application.liquid**

```
...html code here...
 Testing
 {{ content }}
...html code here...
```

**views/layouts/main.liquid**

```
Hello {{ name }}
```

Result should be

"Testing Hello foo", but I only get "Testing Hello".

Any clue? Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquid doesn’t allow evaluating Ruby code as part of the templates, which includes accessing instance variables. You can set locals through a hash:

```
render 'main/index', :locals => { :name => 'foo' }
```

`foo` will then be available in the template.

Comment: Ok, now that works,thanks! but I have no idea why I don't need this kind of thing in ramaze..oh well..